# Can't login into phpmyadmin but password is correct

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to login into my phpmyadmin but it keeps redirecting me back to the login page. My username password should still be correct becuase my website is still functioning and I can even login to my mysql using putty.

I was getting "Cant create/write to file '/tmp/XXXXXXX' Errcode28" error messsage which meant my space is full! I deleted all rows in that table in case this is what causing the issue. I have no idea what to do!

Comment: Free up some disk space.

Comment: @MichaelHampton what should I delete? and where can i find that /tmp folder?

Comment: Delete files you don't need? There is no way for us to know that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's a server! what do you mean delete files you don't need

Comment: It's your server! We don't know why you ran out of disk space. You need to go and actually look at it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just check my disk space only 13% is used!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok for all those out there feeling helpless like me here is the solution:

1. SSH to your server
2. type `df -i` to see if your inode usage is full if yes
3. type `cd/`
4. type this:`echo -e "Inode count for`pwd`:\n"; /bin/ls -A|awk '{print "count=`find \""$0"\"|wc -l`; echo \""$0" \t\t $count\""}'|sh|awk '$NF != "1" {inode=$NF;$NF="";print "printf \"%-50s %8d\\n\" \""$0"\" \""inode"\""}'|sh && printf "%-50s %8d\n" "Total:" "`find ${pwd}|wc -l`"`

   this shows you which directory is using that space the most.
5. cd into that directory and repeat step 4 and 5 until you get to the directory that has the highest usage
6. clear as much as you can in that directory
7. reboot
8. enjoy :)

PS: Stop this downvoting attitude, this is a community for helping eachother.

Comment: you cannot just delete something from the biggest (random) directory on your server, without any understanding about its contents. To analyse disk usage on GNU/Linux, you could use `xdiskusage` (if your server does not have X, you can save `du` output and copy it to other computer with X, where you pass it to xdiskusage).